# My batch program does not run any jobs (Spring Batch 5.0.1 (+ Spring Boot 3.0.3))

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-batch

I tried to create a batch project (for several jobs.)
There are no problems until testing, so I built the project, and run it using command line.
But it finished without any results or any errors. wt...

Here is my code

https://github.com/Aosamesan/batch-no-reponse

I tried...

```bash
java -Dspring.batch.job.name=myJobTestJob -jar blahblah.jar
java -jar blahblah.jar --spring.batch.job.name=myJobTestJob
java -jar blahblah.jar -DJOB_NAME=myJobTestJob
java -DJOB_NAME=myJobTestJob -jar blahblah.jar
```

(with some parameters like `date=2023-03-02`)

but, they didn't work...
I'm confused any errors did not occur...

Comment: Are you running the application from a path that contains spaces? If so, you may be hitting https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34379. It has been fixed in today's Spring Framework 6.0.6 release.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson No, it does not contain spaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sub-classes `DefaultBatchConfiguration`. This tells Spring Boot that you want to take complete control over how Spring Batch is configured and disables its auto-configuration. As a result, the `spring.batch.*` properties that you have configured do not have any effect. You have also disabled the running of jobs on startup.

If you make the following changes, your app should run the specified job on startup:

```
diff --git a/src/main/kotlin/me/aosamesan/batch/jobs/MyJob2Config.kt b/src/main/kotlin/me/aosamesan/batch/jobs/MyJob2Config.kt
index 88ca8b3..f49d33f 100644
--- a/src/main/kotlin/me/aosamesan/batch/jobs/MyJob2Config.kt
+++ b/src/main/kotlin/me/aosamesan/batch/jobs/MyJob2Config.kt
@@ -17,13 +17,13 @@ import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager
 
 @Configuration
 @Import(DataSourceConfig::class)
-class MyJob2Config: DefaultBatchConfiguration() {
+class MyJob2Config {
     companion object {
         private val log by logger()
     }
 
     @Bean
-    fun myJobTest2Step(jobRepository: JobRepository): Step {
+    fun myJobTest2Step(jobRepository: JobRepository, transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager): Step {
         return StepBuilder("myJobTest2Step", jobRepository)
             .tasklet({ _, _ ->
                 log.info("myJobTest2Step")
diff --git a/src/main/kotlin/me/aosamesan/batch/jobs/MyJobConfig.kt b/src/main/kotlin/me/aosamesan/batch/jobs/MyJobConfig.kt
index 9b19006..024a92e 100644
--- a/src/main/kotlin/me/aosamesan/batch/jobs/MyJobConfig.kt
+++ b/src/main/kotlin/me/aosamesan/batch/jobs/MyJobConfig.kt
@@ -17,13 +17,13 @@ import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager
 
 @Configuration
 @Import(DataSourceConfig::class)
-class MyJobConfig: DefaultBatchConfiguration() {
+class MyJobConfig {
     companion object {
         private val log by logger()
     }
 
     @Bean
-    fun myJobTestStep(jobRepository: JobRepository): Step {
+    fun myJobTestStep(jobRepository: JobRepository, transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager): Step {
         return StepBuilder("myJobTestStep", jobRepository)
             .tasklet({ _, _ ->
                 log.info("myJobTestStep")
diff --git a/src/main/resources/application.yml b/src/main/resources/application.yml
index 0c3ba6f..3e2b5ff 100644
--- a/src/main/resources/application.yml
+++ b/src/main/resources/application.yml
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 spring:
   batch:
     job:
-      enabled: false
+      enabled: true
       name: "${JOB_NAME}"
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! but I've tried it before. (I've tried everything I can.) So, I finally found an answer... (set main class as CommandLineJobRunner, and so on. I threw away Spring Boot, and edited code like former Spring Batch)